# C# ListBox не выделять элемент если зажата левая кнопка мыши

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго всем времени суток. Возник вопрос в следующем: 
Есть список который связывается с ListBox через ItemsSource. Далее, если зажать кнопку мыши над одним из элементов ListBox и передвигаться к другим элементам, то следующий элемент над которым окажется мышь станет активным. Подскажите как сделать так что бы не выделялся элемент находящийся под мышью при зажатой левой кнопке мыши. Заранее признателен

Answer (score 0):

```
private void listBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.SetSelected(0, true);
}
```

Comment: при нажатии на элемент списка будет возвращать значение на  1ое значение в списке